# How to remove a PV from a VG without losing the data on it?

Tags: lvm

I want to detach a PV from a VG, *but with preserving the data on it, with the possibility of a re-attach in the future*.

The LVs are completely separated on it (no LV has LEs on both the PV to separate, and on the rest).

Doing this would be easy with losing the data on the PV (pvmove, vgreduce), *but this would be the opposite what I want*.

Is it somehow possible?

Comment: Detach with `vgsplit`, attach with `vgmerge`.

Comment: @frostschutz Thank you very much! Can it be done in hot?

Comment: @frostschutz I checked it. The main VG can remain active (including its LVs), but the LVs on the PV to split has to be deactivated with `lvchange -an`. If you create an answer from it, it will deserve an upvote + accept.

Comment: @frostschutz Sad that you didn't write that answer, maybe it is because der Winter kommt und you have too much to do :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @frostschutz explained, in this case the `vgsplit` tool can be used to split a PV from a VG, and convert it to another, single-PV VG:

```
vgsplit yourvg newvgname /dev/sdx
```

It removes the PV `/dev/sdx` from the VG `yourvg`, and converts it to a new, single-PV VG named `newvgname`.

For `vgsplit`, all the LVs on the PV `/dev/sdx` should be offline, what can be reached by the command `vgchange -an /dev/yourvg/lvname` aften unmounting them.

Later the VGs can be re-joined by the `vgmerge` command.